# From where can I download 32 bit iso images of Arch Linux or Fedora

Tags: arch-linux, fedora, distribution-choice, 32bit

I just need to start learning linux OS. 
So as I have a old pc I need 32 bit images
Is there 32 bit images available for 
1) Fedora
2)Arch linux[image]

Comment: Arch Linux dropped 32-bit support years ago: https://www.archlinux.org/news/the-end-of-i686-support/ ... and Fedora did so last year: https://fedoramagazine.org/in-fedora-31-32-bit-i686-is-86ed/

Comment: So there are not available now? Because I use 32 bit i386 processor

Comment: Nope. Maybe you can go for Lubuntu: https://lubuntu.net/downloads/. Which CPU do you have?

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E440 @ 2.00 GHz 2.00 GHz

Comment: I can't find a E440. There's an E4400, which apparently has a 64-bit instruction set according to https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/29753/intel-core-2-duo-processor-e4400-2m-cache-2-00-ghz-800-mhz-fsb.html ... So maybe try a 64-bit distribution anyway?

Comment: I will post my system information

Comment: The 32-bit you see there is your Windows installation. The E4400 supports 64-bit according to Intel Ark, so you should be able to run a 64-bit distro on it.

Comment: So will I be able to run parrot os on my pc? It is 64 bit iso image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104863/discussion-between-noone-noone-and-muru).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arch Linux dropped 32-bit support some years ago, but a separate project called Arch Linux 32 continues to support 32-bit Arch. See https://archlinux32.org/.

Comment: Btw, Google is your friend. Searching for "32-bit arch Linux" returns archlinux32.org as the first hit.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora has no 32-bit anymore. Individual packages are available, however.

You might want to look at [CentOS](http://centos.org), that one is still available for i386.